# Looping through JSON with PHP to get children

Tags: php, json, foreach, children

I've been trying all morning to do what would appear to be something quite simple and I'm failing miserably.

I have an API request which returns valid JSON data and I need to loop through the various values in PHP to get several nodes into my application.

Here is a snippet of the JSON

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "date": "2015-06-01",
        "rates": [
            {
                "id": 1592,
                "name": "Weekend promotion",
                "room_rates": [
                    {
                        "room_type_id": 66,
                        "room_type_code": "DLK",
                        "sold": 0,
                        "sell_limit": null,
                        "availability": 25,
                        "out_of_order": 0,
                        "single": 85,
                        "double": 85,
                        "extra_adult": null,
                        "child": null
                    },
                    {
                        "room_type_id": 90,
                        "room_type_code": "DLT",
                        "sold": 0,
                        "sell_limit": null,
                        "availability": 11,
                        "out_of_order": 0,
                        "single": 85,
                        "double": 85,
                        "extra_adult": null,
                        "child": null
                    },
```

And this is what I'm trying to do, but I keep getting the following error (edited to update cURL response):

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 135

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 135

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 135

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 135
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Line 135 is this:

**foreach($responseData as $mydata)**

```
$url = 'https://myapi.com/availability?token=xx&from_date='.$from_date.'&to_date='.$to_date;

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
); 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($result, TRUE);

// Put everyting to the screen with var_dump;
var_dump($responseData);

// With print_r ( useful for arrays );
//print_r($responseData);

// List just review ratings with foreach;
foreach($responseData as $mydata)
{
    foreach($mydata->results as $values) {
        echo $values->rates . "\n";
    }

}
```

I need to be able to return the following nodes....

```
results>rates>name
results>rates>room_rates>room_type_id
results>rates>room_rates>availability
```

I'm completely stuck!

The var_dump does return my array, so the cURL is working correctly now.

Simon

Comment: 1st, saying line 126 is the foreach when you have two foreaches isn't helpful. Is it `foreach($responseData as $mydata)` or `foreach($mydata->results as $values)`? I'm guessing it's the second one looking at your JSON. 2nd, have you tried `var_dump($responseData)` to make sure you have what you expect?

Comment: check if foreach entry is really array or array object. if not foreach can not iterate this.

Comment: @daremachine Yes it can, foreach can iterate an array object fine. See this eval.in - https://eval.in/373679

Comment: Sorry, it's the first foreach, missed a word in my question! And yes, it dumps the data fine.

Comment: and $mydata->results too ? because "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" is bad entry ... check results

Comment: Simon, can you please edit your question to include the `var_dump($responseData)` output?

Comment: Also, what happens if you try `foreach ($responseData->results[0]->roomRates as $roomRates): echo $roomRates->room_type_id; endforeach;`

Comment: just added the dump result, which is: int(1)

Comment: ok simon but int(1) is not an array

Comment: @SimonHume Well that's wrong, that's not what you'd expect. I think the problem is your `cURL` request.

Comment: simon check response

Comment: Hmm, I include two date variables inside my cURL request, if those are incorrect I get a JSON response with a 500 error, so I'm not really sure what I've done wrong there as the URL is fine if I call it in a browser for example.

Comment: @SimonHume I've added an answer and explained why you're getting the `int(1)` instead of the JSON. In the future, `var_dump`, check you are actually getting the data you expect, don't assume it's correct.

Comment: cheers for that, getting somewhere now, now just to sort this foreach issue out, now the cURL is behaving properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your cURL request is to blame, you're not telling cURL you're expecting a response, so cURL just passes back a boolean success for your initial request, it sent it successfully.

From the [PHP curl_exec page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

> **Returns TRUE on success** or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

It's succeeding, but you're not telling it you're expecting a response, so it returns `TRUE`.

Try this:

```
$url = 'https://myapi.com/api?token=xxx&from_date='.$from_date.'&to_date='.$to_date;

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page <-- This is the important one that tells cURL you want a response.
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
); 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

**2nd error**

Now we've got cURL working lets address the result. Remember that when JSON is converted each brace (`{`) will produce an object, and each square bracket (`[`) will produce an array. So if we follow your JSON we can see that you will get an object back, containing the property `results`. You can access that using `$responseData->results`.

In your second foreach you're trying to access the property of an object. Results isn't an object, it's an array (look at your JSON, it contains a `[`, so it's an array). To get the rates follow through the JSON string and you'll see you need to do this:

```
foreach($responseData->results[0]->rates as $rate) {
    echo $rate->id . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, tried that and it does now return  proper array result in the dump. Still getting the error on the original foreach here: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 135

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 135

Comment: So update your questions with what you're getting in the dump now. I'm guessing you're just doing the `foreach` on the wrong part.

Comment: @SimonHume I've updated my answer to cover your second issue. You're not following the structure of JSON and what `json_decode` turns it into.